# Where can I find ebaysdk maven repository?

Tags: maven, ebay-api

The title says all: I can't find ebay sdk on maven

I've tried to use the pom.xml I found in  eBaySDKJava897 (samples consoleAddItem)
but maven can't find dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ebay</groupId>
    <artifactId>ebaysdkcore</artifactId>
    <version>861</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.tonicsoft.ebay/ebaysdkcore/981.0.0

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.tonicsoft.ebay</groupId>
        <artifactId>ebaysdkcore</artifactId>
        <version>981.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```